# Django-Haystack: How to pass extra context with FacetedSearchView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-haystack

This is my current view.

```
class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):

    form_class = FacetedProductSearchForm
    facet_fields = ['TopCategory']
    template_name = 'shop-grid-ls.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = 'object_list'


    extra = TopCategory.objects.all()

    def extra_context(self):
        return {
            'extra': self.extra,
        }
```

I can't access the `extra` objects in my template. How can I pass context through a FacetedSearchView.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the `get_context_data` method of the parent class.
Try this:

```
class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):
    # ...

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(FacetedSearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        extra = TopCategory.objects.all()
        context.update({'extra': extra})
        return context
```

You shouldn't define that variable `extra` outside the method. I hope you know the difference between class attributes and instance attributes.